# Programming on com objects in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a com object from a windows platform application that is written by another language.
I can work with it using winform in C#.but when I want to use it in asp.net ,I should take it on sta threads , Otherwise I get this exception:

> ActiveX control 'xxx' cannot be instantiated because the current
>   thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

But I have a problem. I have to connect to a server by this com object and keep this connection for next requests (such as i did on winform).

is any way (such as static classes that dose not work here too) that this com object be public for all of the users that request a command.

I put some of my code:

```
public static class MyServer
{


 public static string Error = "";
public static string Result = "";
private static MyComObject a = null;
private static bool IsConnected = false;

private static void Connect()
{
    a = MyComObject;
    a.CreateControl();

    a.ReceivedData += new EventHandler(a_Received);
    a.Err += new EventHandler(a_Err);
    a.Connected += new EventHandler(a_Connected);
    a.Disconnected += new EventHandler(a_Disconnected);


    a.Connect(username , password);//connect to server and takes a long time
}

static void a_Disconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsConnected = false;
}

static void a_Connected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsConnected = true;
}

static void a_Err(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Error += "Err Method = errCode : " + e.errCode.ToString() + " -- errMessage : " + e.errMessage + "\n";
}

static void a_Received(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Result += "Connected Method = " + e.str + "\n";
}

public static void GetResult(string Command)
{
    if (!IsConnected)
    {
        Connect();
    }
    a.Send(Command);
}

public static void DisConnect()
{
    a.Disconnect();
    a = null;
    GC.Collect();
}
}
```

Comment: If your COM component is an ActiveX Control (that is, a GUI component that expects a Win32 window message pump) then you cannot use it in headless server-side code... at least not without serious difficulty.

Comment: can i create in winform and make connection between winform and asp.net (to send and receive data) using http prootocols or any thing else